# Failure to do-release-upgrade from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS (32bit)

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, apt, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I just tried to use do-release-upgrade to upgrade from (32bit) 16.04 LTS to 18.04
LTS and it failed with:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4 is installed
 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings : Depends: libproxy1v5 (= 0.4.15-1) but 0.4.11-5ubuntu1 is installed
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 229-4ubuntu21.27) but 237-3ubuntu10.39 is installed
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 229-4ubuntu21.27) but 237-3ubuntu10.39 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Before the attempted upgrade, I had what I thought was a clean install of
ubuntu 16.04 with no third-party repositories or PPAs. In the past, I did
have those things for a kernel that knew about a Hauppage TV card that I was
trying to use but it didn't work so I undid all of that and went back to a
standard installation and dpkg --audit showed no problems. But I suspect
that that is the source of my problems. I haven't had an Ubuntu or Debian
upgrade go wrong in over a decade and this was the first time that I'd used
a third-party repository.

I've searched everywhere and tried all the usually recommended things like:

```
# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-bin : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) but 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4 is installed
 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings : Depends: libproxy1v5 (= 0.4.15-1) but 0.4.11-5ubuntu1 is installed
 systemd : Depends: libsystemd0 (= 229-4ubuntu21.27) but 237-3ubuntu10.39 is installed
 udev : Depends: libudev1 (= 229-4ubuntu21.27) but 237-3ubuntu10.39 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

# dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:i386:
 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:i386 depends on libproxy1v5 (= 0.4.15-1); however:
  Version of libproxy1v5:i386 on system is 0.4.11-5ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglib2.0-bin:
 libglib2.0-bin depends on libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4); however:
  Version of libglib2.0-0:i386 on system is 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:i386
 libglib2.0-bin
```

There are no held packages or pinning preferences.

The apt-cache policies of the problem packages look like this:

```
# apt-cache policy libglib2.0-0
libglib2.0-0:
  Installed: 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4
  Candidate: 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4
  Version table:
     2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages
     2.56.1-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
 *** 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The above looks to me like it should be happy to upgrade.
But I don't really understand all this.

```
# apt-cache policy libproxy1v5
libproxy1v5:
  Installed: 0.4.11-5ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.4.15-1
  Version table:
     0.4.15-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
 *** 0.4.11-5ubuntu1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Same with the above.

```
# apt-cache policy libsystemd0
libsystemd0:
  Installed: 237-3ubuntu10.39
  Candidate: 237-3ubuntu10.39
  Version table:
 *** 237-3ubuntu10.39 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     237-3ubuntu10.38 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages
     237-3ubuntu10 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
```

The above looks like a newer version is installed than the one that systemd
requires (229-4ubuntu21.27). I don't understand how that could happen or why
systemd would require an older version that what is available for 18.04.

```
# apt-cache policy libudev1
libudev1:
  Installed: 237-3ubuntu10.39
  Candidate: 237-3ubuntu10.39
  Version table:
 *** 237-3ubuntu10.39 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     237-3ubuntu10.38 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main i386 Packages
     237-3ubuntu10 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
```

Same as the above.

A dpkg audit shows:

```
# dpkg --audit
The following packages have been unpacked but not yet configured.
They must be configured using dpkg --configure or the configure
menu option in dselect for them to work:
 libglib2.0-bin       Programs for the GLib library
 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:i386 automatic proxy configuration management library (G

The following packages are only half installed, due to problems during
installation. The installation can probably be completed by retrying it;
the packages can be removed using dselect or dpkg --remove:
 systemd-shim         shim for systemd
```

The systemd-shim package is in a wierd state:

```
rH  systemd-shim  9-1bzr4ubuntu1         i386    shim for systemd
```

"rH" means Remove and Half-installed.

Trying to dpkg --configure them does no good:

```
# dpkg --configure libglib2.0-bin
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libglib2.0-bin:
 libglib2.0-bin depends on libglib2.0-0 (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4); however:
  Version of libglib2.0-0:i386 on system is 2.48.2-0ubuntu4.4.

dpkg: error processing package libglib2.0-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libglib2.0-bin

# dpkg --configure libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:i386
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:i386:
 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:i386 depends on libproxy1v5 (= 0.4.15-1); however:
  Version of libproxy1v5:i386 on system is 0.4.11-5ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings:i386
```

I even attempted the suggestion to dpkg --remove systemd-shim, assuming that
it would let me bail out:

```
# dpkg --remove systemd-shim
(Reading database ... 377504 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing systemd-shim (9-1bzr4ubuntu1) ...
Removing 'diversion of /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service to /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd by systemd-shim'
dpkg-divert: error: rename involves overwriting '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service' with
  different file '/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.systemd1.service.systemd', not allowed
dpkg: error processing package systemd-shim (--remove):
 installed systemd-shim package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd-shim
```

I even thought of uninstalling the problematic packages but since they
include libglibc, systemd and udev, that sounds like a disaster waiting
to happen.

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix these package problems?

I really don't want to do a fresh install because I don't want to have to
reconfigure all of the services that I've configured over the years. It
would be a huge task that I'll never have time for. I'd rather go back
to xenial/16.04. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.